# Using ref parameters in linq

Tags: c#, linq, pass-by-reference

I have a function that takes a ref parameter and would like to use it in a linq query but the compiler complains.

The function is called BreakLine and breaks a string up into lines based on a line length, the ref parameter is used to keep track of where it is in the string on each call:

```
string BreakLine(string text, int lineLimit, ref offset);
```

The query is:

```
from pt in productText 
let offset = 0
from ll in lineLimits
select new Line() { Text = BreakLine(pt, ll, ref offset) }
```

(Line is a simple data class)

The error is:

"Cannot pass the range variable 'offset' as an out or ref parameter"

Any way to workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Func<string, int, Line> lineFunc = (pt, ll) =>
{
    int offset = 0;
    return new Line() { Text = BreakLine(pt, ll, ref offset) };
};
var test = from pt in productText
            from ll in lineLimits
            select lineFunc(pt, ll);
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `offset` has no type specified. Try to change the `BreakLine` method signature into this:

```
string BreakLine(string text, int lineLimit, ref int offset);
```

...but I guess that is just a typo in your question. The *real* problem you have is that you get compiler error [CS1939](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545970(VS.90).aspxvalid.). Quote from the documentation:

> A range variable is a read-only
>   variable that is introduced in a query
>   expression and serves as an identifier
>   for each successive element in a
>   source sequence. Because it cannot be
>   modified in any way, there is no point
>   in passing it by `ref` or `out`.
>   Therefore, both operations are not
>   valid.

Comment: I left out the type of the parameter by mistake, its actually as you have it. Removing the ref keyword just gives another error cause it doesnt match the method signature.